# angular-ui datepicker max-date doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker, angular-ui

I am trying to get the `min-date` and `max-date` to be set from the `datepicker-options`, but have been unsuccessful. A code snippet is attached.

Any help? Thanks!

```js
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('DatepickerDemoCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.today = function() {
    $scope.dt = new Date();
  };
  $scope.today();

  $scope.dateOptions = {
    formatYear: 'yy',
    minDate: '05/01/2015',
    startingDay: 1
  };

  $scope.formats =['dd/MM/yyyy', 'dd-MMMM-yyyy', 'yyyy/MM/dd', 'dd.MM.yyyy', 'shortDate'];
  $scope.format = $scope.formats[0];

  var tomorrow = new Date();
  tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);
  var afterTomorrow = new Date();
  afterTomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 2);
  $scope.events =
    [
      {
        date: tomorrow,
        status: 'full'
      },
      {
        date: afterTomorrow,
        status: 'partially'
      }
    ];

  $scope.getDayClass = function(date, mode) {
    if (mode === 'day') {
      var dayToCheck = new Date(date).setHours(0,0,0,0);

      for (var i=0;i<$scope.events.length;i++){
        var currentDay = new Date($scope.events[i].date).setHours(0,0,0,0);

        if (dayToCheck === currentDay) {
          return $scope.events[i].status;
        }
      }
    }

    return '';
  };
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.13/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.13.0.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>

<style>
  .full button span {
    background-color: limegreen;
    border-radius: 32px;
    color: black;
  }
  .partially button span {
    background-color: orange;
    border-radius: 32px;
    color: black;
  }
</style>
<div ng-controller="DatepickerDemoCtrl">
    <pre>Selected date is: <em>{{dt | date:'fullDate' }}</em></pre>

    <h4>Inline</h4>
    <div style="display:inline-block; min-height:290px;">
      <datepicker ng-model="dt" datepicker-options="dateOptions" class="well well-sm" custom-class="getDayClass(date, mode)"></datepicker>
    </div>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: its already an open bug https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/2189

Comment: This bug appears to be closed

Comment: that means @Jacob Finamore solution work for you..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<datepicker ng-model="dt" minDate="'05/01/2015'" datepicker-options="dateOptions" class="well well-sm" custom-class="getDayClass(date, mode)"></datepicker>` try this, put the minDate in the markup

Comment: also try switching around the order of the date such as `2015/05/01` or even with dashes like `2015-05-01`

Comment: Shouldn't I be able to put it via the options as per the documentation?

Comment: i would have to agree but have you tried this way yet?