# How to able to set min and max date?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am using below library. For using in DateTime picker control, but i am not able to set min and max date.

```
https://github.com/kineticsocial/angularjs-datetime-picker
```

Download location: `https://www.npmjs.com/package/angularjs-datetime-picker`

View file code:

```
<input ng-model="eta" required id="eta" style="height:32px; border-bottom-width:thin;border-top-width:thin;border-left-width:thin;border-right-width:thin ;" datetime-picker min-date="minDate" date-format="MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm" close-on-select="true" readonly size="30" />
```

Please advice me how to set min and max date.

Thanks...

Comment: you may try this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30200122/angular-ui-datepicker-max-date-doesnt-work-properly

Comment: Use datepicker-options="{minDate: yourScopeMinDate}"

Comment: its not working

Answer (score 0):

It is NOT yet supported at the moment:
https://github.com/kineticsocial/angularjs-datetime-picker/issues/2